# Electron ipc using remote website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, electron

I'm creating a [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) `BrowserWindow` using a remote url, so I can't really use the `var ipc = require('ipc');` syntax to include ipc.  It is possible to send messages from a remote url to the electron main-process? If so where can I get the javascript source for it?

Or maybe there is a better way to pass info to electron main-process? Just need to send the logged in user info.

Comment: Why can't you just use IPC? The page might be loaded from a remote URL but the JavaScript in it is still executed by Electron.

Comment: @MattHarrison Ideally the remote page will work independently of the electron app.

Comment: Sounds like you want an API that both your website and native application (electron) can access.

Comment: Yes but I think I still need a way for the website to pass the loggedIn user id to electrons main-process. The main-process would then be able to get information relevant to that user.

Answer (score 6):

This question has been asked quite sometime back, but I think this could still be useful. The way you can inject Javascript into the browser window is using the preload lag, in the web preferences, add the options:

```
const window = new BrowserWindow({
                    webPreferences:{
                     preload: <path_to>/preload.js
                    }
                   })
```

```
// preload.js

const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

In the webpage of you the external url you are loading you can directly use `window.ipcRenderer`.

Answer (score 2):

If found that setting the **nodeIntegration to true** as part of the **webPreferences** fixed this issue and allowed "require" the ipc module and call a send on it

```
main.js

 var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        show: false,
        parent: mainWindow,
        modal: true,
        webPreferences:{
      nodeIntegration: true
     }
  });
```

Please be aware of the security implications of setting this is you are possibly executing scripts from unknown origins

https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it.  Using angular so I made a factory, but the same try/catch method should work for anything. If run from electron the ipc messages are sent, otherwise they are ignored.

```
angular.module('IpcFactory', [])
.factory('IpcFactory', function(){

    var ipcAvailable;

    try{
        var ipc = require('ipc');
        ipcAvailable = true;
    }
    catch(e){
        ipcAvailable = false;
    }

    return {

        ipcAvailable: ipcAvailable,

        send: function(event, message){
            var self = this;
            if(self.ipcAvailable){
                ipc.send(event, message);
            }
        },

        on: function(event, fn){
            var self = this;
            if(self.ipcAvailable){
                ipc.on(event, fn());
            }
        }

    };

});
```